# How to keep Sentry error handling but don't send to Sentry backend

Tags: javascript, web, error-handling, sentry

I'd like to disable sending errors to Sentry in my dev environment. **However** I'd like to keep all of Sentry's error handling intact (besides sending the errors to Sentry's backend) so that I can test it in dev. For example, I have a custom event processor added to Sentry with `Sentry.addGlobalEventProcessor` and I'd like that to continue running (so I can test it).

Things I've tried:

- **Set `enabled: false`**. This does not work because it entirely disables Sentry (event processors don't fire anymore):

  ```js
  Sentry.init({
      dsn: '...',
      enabled: false,
  });
  ```
- **Set `sampleRate: 0`**. This effectively does the same thing as setting `enabled: false`:

  ```js
  Sentry.init({
      dsn: '...',
      enabled: true,
      sampleRate: 0,
  });
  ```
- **Set `dsn: ''`**. Same as above, Sentry simple stops doing anything:

  ```js
  Sentry.init({
      dsn: '',
      enabled: true,
  });
  ```

Comment: I suppose I _could_ add a service worker and block all fetches to Sentry in dev but I'm hoping for a simpler solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone has a better solution, it looks like the easiest way to accomplish this is to always return `null` in `beforeSend` and `beforeSendTransaction`:

```js
Sentry.init({
    dsn: '...',
    enabled: true,
    beforeSend() {
        return null;
    },
    beforeSendTransaction() {
        return null;
    },
});
```

This maintains all Sentry processing (including custom event processors) but prevents Sentry from sending any events to the backend. Note that, oddly, this still results in a request sent to sentry that notes how many events were discarded (not sent):

```json
{"discarded_events":[{"reason":"before_send","category":"error","quantity":2}]}
```

This seems to not matter, so I'm going with this!